# How to launch spring boot application with cloud-bus via custom auto-configuration?

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-cloud-bus

Some time ago I found out that my spring-boot application had been launching slowly via @EnableAutoConfiguration. Then I decided to create custom configuration to speed up a process. I tried to @Import all needed configurations and I faced with issue of unknown beans:

```
Description:

Parameter 0 of method streamBusBridge in org.springframework.cloud.bus.BusStreamAutoConfiguration required a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge' that could not be found.


Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.cloud.stream.function.StreamBridge' in your configuration.
```

It seems that I've already used all cloud-bus configurations:

```
    PathServiceMatcherAutoConfiguration.class,
    BindingsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    BusAutoConfiguration.class,
    BindingServiceConfiguration.class,
    BindersHealthIndicatorAutoConfiguration.class,
    ChannelsEndpointAutoConfiguration.class,
    BusRefreshAutoConfiguration.class,
    FunctionConfiguration.class,
    BusStreamAutoConfiguration.class,
    BusJacksonAutoConfiguration.class
```

What should I add to launch my application via custom auto-configuration?

**Spring-boot:** v2.6.6

**Spring-cloud-bus:** v3.1.2

**Java:** 17

Comment: Enable the auto configuration back, set `debug=true` to the app properties, run your app and collect all the "matched" and unconditional auto configurations from the debug report. This will give you the full list of the ones you need to import manually.

Comment: I suppose that the order in @Import matters. How can I figure out an order?

Comment: Import order should not affect how the configurations are applied. I don't think you can enforce the order at all with manual import, since during autoconfiguration the order is maintained via `@AutoConfigureBefore`, `@AutoConfigureAfter`. Generally importing autoconfigurations is a bad idea. "Auto-configurations must be loaded that way only [spring.factories]. Make sure that they are defined in a specific package space and that they are never the target of component scanning." (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.developing-auto-configuration)